MoveApps API access via R
I use Movebank to organize telemetry data from collared animals on the landscape. I’ve been loving the automated, scheduled workflows that I can create with the related analysis platform MoveApps. I’m very interested in connecting to the app output using an API via R. I’ve been reading up on how to do this, but the examples I’ve linked to below seem to be mostly focused on displaying the results on a webpage.
https://docs.moveapps.org/#/API
https://github.com/movestore/movestore.github.io/blob/master/web-partner-api/example.html
https://docs.moveapps.org/web-partner-api/example.html
https://www.proquest.com/openview/63bd63824208b8d6706708fe101beb0c/1?pq-origsite=gscholar&cbl=2049297
I haven’t found an example directing users how to access the output via the API in R. I believe this is possible - there are many examples out there on how to pull data via APIs in R - but I'm a relative noob to this kind of procedure and finding it hard to figure out where to begin. Has anyone done this before? I think this kind of connection between MoveApps and R would be fantastic for automated tasks and all levels of code-dabblers.

You can use httr to send requests to the API.  Here's an example:
library(move2)
library(httr)

# Credentials from the example page
username <- '8b536ed8-a681-4786-aa01-b26040106f9f'
token <- 'bdl@2nq@9SD!i31a1M7HxG7GQG93IQ0a'

# Insert username into URL
url <- sprintf("https://www.moveapps.org/web-partner/v1/workflowInstances/%s/artifacts/index", username)

# Send GET request
r <- GET(url = url, authenticate(username, token))

# Parse the response
res <- r |>
  content(as = "parsed", simplifyDataFrame = TRUE)

This results in a nested list of the workflow information:
str(res)
List of 3
 $ workflowInstanceId   : chr "8b536ed8-a681-4786-aa01-b26040106f9f"
 $ workflowInstanceTitle: chr "Workflow Instance 001"
 $ results              :'data.frame':  9 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ appPositionInWorkflow: int [1:9] 0 1 2 3 3 4 4 5 5
  ..$ appTitle             : chr [1:9] "Movebank Location move1" "Remove Outliers move1" "Filter Last X Days move1" "Animated Map (moveVis) move1" ...
  ..$ fileName             : chr [1:9] "app-output.rds" "app-output.rds" "app-output.rds" "animation_moveVis.mp4" ...
  ..$ mimeType             : chr [1:9] "application/r-rds" "application/r-rds" "application/r-rds" "video/quicktime" ...
  ..$ fileSize             : int [1:9] 3194278 2932993 2932986 134280 2932986 15047 3683428 3683428 6017277
  ..$ modifiedAt           : chr [1:9] "2023-03-17T10:00:59.892611Z" "2023-03-10T03:15:53.323066Z" "2023-03-10T03:16:02.329737Z" "2023-03-10T03:18:35.108558Z" ...
  ..$ links                :'data.frame':   9 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ self: chr [1:9] "https://www.moveapps.org/web-partner/v1/workflowInstances/8b536ed8-a681-4786-aa01-b26040106f9f/apps/0/results/app-output.rds" "https://www.moveapps.org/web-partner/v1/workflowInstances/8b536ed8-a681-4786-aa01-b26040106f9f/apps/1/results/app-output.rds" "https://www.moveapps.org/web-partner/v1/workflowInstances/8b536ed8-a681-4786-aa01-b26040106f9f/apps/2/results/app-output.rds" "https://www.moveapps.org/web-partner/v1/workflowInstances/8b536ed8-a681-4786-aa01-b26040106f9f/apps/3/results/a"| __truncated__ ...

Now to access a file:
# Download first file
tmp <- tempfile()
w1 <- GET(res$results$links$self[1], authenticate(username, token), write_disk(tmp))

# Read downloaded file
movedat <- readRDS(tmp)

# Plot
plot(movedat)



Really slick. Thanks so much, I think this post will help a lot of folks!
